# Converting C++ code to C, array of structs

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct

I'm converting C++ code to C for an exercise (we are just learning c++ now), and I am lost at this part.

First, the c++ code:

```
Point()
{
    x = y = 0;
}

main()
{
    const int N = 200;
    Point *A = new Point[N], sum;    
}
```

Here's my C version of it:

```
struct Point //constructor
{
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;

main()
{
    int N = 200;
    Point* A = malloc(N * sizeof(*Point[]));
}
```

That should give you an idea of what I'm trying to do. Questions:

1. Is `sum` in the C++ code the C++ `sum function, or is it a`Pointstruct`?
2. For allocating the memory in C, I don't think my method works. Should I do a for loop where it `malloc`s each index of A[]? (A should be an array of `Point` `struct`s).

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Got asked for the context of the code.

Here's the whole C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>

// a point on the integer grid

struct Point
{
  // constructor
  Point()
  {
    x = y = 0;
  }

  // add point componentwise
  void add(const Point &p)
  {
    x += p.x;
    y += p.y;
  }

  // print to standard output
  void print() const
  {
    std::cout << "[" << x << "," << y << "]" << std::endl;
  }

  // data
  int x, y;
};


int main()
{
  const int N = 200;
  Point *A = new Point[N], sum;

  for (int i=0; i < N; ++i) {
    sum.print();
    A[i].x = i; A[i].y = -i;
    sum.add(A[i]);
  }
  sum.print();
  delete [] A;
}
```

Ultimately, I have to emulate that in C. Currently stuck at the question I asked: re: what does that line do. I have since figured out that I need to make a struct of Point called sum, and print that after running the add function on all its members.

Comment: Your C++ code is incomplete and doesn't make much sense. Could you post some (minimal) real code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your C version:

```
struct Point //constructor
{
int x;
int y;
} Point;
```

should be:

```
typedef struct //constructor
{
int x;
int y;
} Point;
```

Because in your case, you defined a global variable named `Point`.

And, the C programming language has the `const` keyword as C++ as well, so you can do this in the C language:

```
const int N = 200;
```

And the C++ code:

```
Point *A = new Point[N], sum;
```

In C version, should be:

```
Point *A = malloc(N * sizeof(Point)), sum;
```

But in this version, the memory isn't initialized by zero.

You can use the `calloc` function instead of the `malloc` to allocate memory and initialize it with zero:

```
Point *A = calloc(N, sizeof(Point)), sum;
```

Then back to your question:

> 1. Is sum in the c++ code the c++ sum function, or is it a Point struct?

It is a `Point` type variable.

> 2. For allocating the memory in C, I don't think my method works. Should I do a for loop where it mallocs each index of A[]? (A should be an array of Point structs).

No, there's no necessary to write a `for` loop. The `malloc` function will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Except in the C++ code the `Point` members re zero-initialized, and in the C version they are not.

Comment: In C there is no need, nor is it recommnended to cast the result of `malloc/calloc/realloc`!

Comment: Thank you. first time in the site and you covered about all I needed.

Comment: @Murbly I'm a newbie here too. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> > 1. Is sum in the c++ code the c++ sum function, or is it a Point struct?

In your case, it is a Point struct.

```
   Point *A = new Point[N], sum;
```

is equivalent to:

```
   Point *A = new Point[N];
   Point sum; //I have no idea why naming is sum
```

If you need `Point*` for `sum`, you should write it in the following way:

```
     Point *A = new Point[N], *sum;
```

> > 2. For allocating the memory in C, I don't think my method works

It does not work, syntax is wrong. Try:

EDIT: thanks to @mch, you should not use cast for `malloc`.

```
typedef struct Point Point;
Point* A = malloc(N * sizeof(Point));
```

Comment: don't cast the return value of malloc in c: http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/3684343

Comment: @mch Thanks, good to learn that. I guess I did not write C for a long time.

Comment: and without a typedef you need to write `struct Point` instead of `Point`

Comment: Also, the C version does not zero initialize the data.

Comment: @juanchopanza I agree with that